# Could a verb 'to suggest' mean 'to say' or 'to express an opinion'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Syria Envoy Suggests Donald Trump Has Limited Window to Work With
>   Russia

As I can see from the context in this sencence a verb 'to suggest' means 'to say' or 'to assert'. Am I right?

Comment: **suggest** is not as definite as "assert".  The envoy could have said that he *believed* the window was limited, or that the window *might be* limited, or that the window *is probably* very limited, or words to that effect.

Comment: While *suggest* is *to propose* or *to offer for consideration (The Free Dictionary) the word is frequently used disparagingly, as in: *I suggest that you're talking nonsense* or *I suggest that he's not your brightest pupil*. In such cases the *I suggest* merely serves to offer a pretense of civility.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you for the explanation, but what about my example? Is it correct to perceive 'to suggest' in this context as 'to say'?

Comment: @sliser - The Syrian envoy is a person, so presumably he (or she)  suggested it by saying it, yes.  I suppose it's possible that he wrote it instead of saying it, but the meaning is basically the same.  Note that *suggest* is sometimes used more loosely, as in "The bulk of the historical evidence suggests that..." where you couldn't literally interpret it as *say*.

Comment: @stangdon Let me get this straight, the envoy expresses his opinion in direct way, not hinting or implying

Comment: @sliser - "Suggest" is slightly vague: he could have said it directly, or he could have hinted or implied it.  Saying "Syria Envoy **Says**" or "Syria Envoy **States**" would definitely mean that he stated it directly.

Comment: @sliser In response to your question, *to say* is generally understood as a neutral way of stating something. On the other hand, there are many ways of suggesting (i.e. proposing) something: in speech, in writing, in gesture and in images. In this instance, the Syrian envoy appears to be merely putting forward the proposition. It's not clear whether he/she is doing so in speech or writing.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that in this context **"suggest"** means *'to say'* or *'to assert'*

In fact it has the meaning of *"put forward for consideration"*

- The word ["suggest"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suggest) has very many meanings and is used differently in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

When you suggest something to X, you are trying to let X come to a conclusion.  So it's not the same as asserting something - when you assert something you explicitly state the conclusion.

Also, when you say X, it's generally understood that you directly communicated X in some fashion.  Suggesting is typically indirect - something might be said, but not exactly what might have been concluded, therefore not really synonymous with saying.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that will use "to suggest" for, when we have to recommend someone to do something which is very important.
Then we use to suggest or to recommend..etc

but "to say" is just normal conversation when we would like to say just to do..either person will accept or not. It means one kind of opinion.

Comment: Both recommend and suggest aren't very important, but might be helpful. On the other hand "advise" is mostly important.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your answer, like any dictionary entries? Also, can you explain how your answer relates to OP's context?